# Difference between (Facts and Predicates) && (Single and Determ)

Tags: visual-prolog

I just wonder,  what is the difference between "facts" and "predicates" section in prolog ?

and what is the difference between "single" and "determ" keyword ?

Comment: what prolog are you using ? `single`,`determ` are not keywords I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to point the obvious: "Facts section" is for facts, facts are predicates that are always true, are used to describe some properties.

`Single` and `determ` are "fact mode", used optionally in a fact declaration, `Single` means the fact always has one and only one value, `determ` means the fact can have zero or one value.

Comment: thanks , I understood the second part, 
but about the first part,  I just understand that I cannot use "Single"
 and "determ" keywords  in "predicates' section and I can only use "nondeterm" keyword in the "predicates" Section.
but in "facts" section i can use "determ ","single","nondeterm"
so when would i  use predicates section if it could be replaced with "facts" section ?

Comment: you can not replace predicates with facts, because as I wrote are different things, a fact is a predicate, but a predicate not always is a fact! A fact is always true, like `sun(yellow)` but a predicate can be true or false, it depends of which terms contain, generally is the thing you have evaluate, like `sun(Color)` (`Color` is now a variable).

Answer (score 3):

**Fact** in prolog is substitution of predicat like table in db *Table(Column1,Column2, ...)* indeed `Facts` takes the form like `Fact(Arg1,Arg2)` which gives us {true,false} values ONLY for the specific constants mentioned inside *"()"*

so Fact is a complex term or predicate of arguments indeed, `Args` are not a variables,are individual constants.

**example**

```
father(fathername,childname).
```

**Rule** are also substitutions of predicate takes the form

```
rule_type1(+In_Args,?Out_Args) :- body .  
rule_type2(+In_Args) :- body . % (true,false)
rule_type3 :- body .
```

it order to generate data from facts or from logique rules derived into body through Querys

**example**

```
max(X,Y,Z) :- X>=Y -> Z=X ; Z=Y .

?- max(3,5,Z).   /* give us */ Z=5
```

in visual-prolog `Facts` can be declared with several optional keywords:

**Facts declared with the keyword determ.**

The keyword `determ` determins that the facts database can only contain one instance of a fact (database predicate) fact_N(...) declared with this keyword. So if you try to `assert` one and then a second such fact into the database, the Visual Prolog engine will generate runtime error. (1041 Assert to a fact declared as determ, but fact already exists).
 [example](http://www.aistudy.com/program/prolog/visual_prolog/Declaring%20the%20facts-sections.htm)

**Facts declared with the keyword single.**

The keyword `single` before a fact fact_N declaration determines that one and only one instance of a fact must always exist:

Since single facts must be already known when the program calls Goal; therefore, single facts must be initialized in a clauses section in the program's source code.

**For example:**

```
FACTS
single singleFact(STRING, STRING)
CLAUSES
singleFact("","").
```